# how to send external image within email body part?

Tags: c#, html, .net, image, email

i want to send email which includes `HTML contents with images`. so, any way to send external image within body content not as an attachment.

My image resides under `image` folder of my project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the .net `MailMessage` type you can set `IsBodyHtml = true;` and then write your `<img>` tags as you normally would using absolute paths e.g. `www.example.com/images/image.png`.

For cleanliness sake, i read my HTML from an XML file, e.g.

```
private MailMessage GetHtmlEmail()
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    XmlTextReader xReader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("~/ConfigFiles/Email.xml"));

    while (xReader.Read())
    {
        switch (xReader.Name)
        {
            case "ToAddress":
                mail.To.Add(xReader.ReadElementContentAs(typeof(string), null).ToString());
                break;
            case "FromAddress":
                mail.From = new MailAddress(xReader.ReadElementContentAs(typeof(string), null).ToString());
                break;
            case "Subject":
                mail.Subject = xReader.ReadElementContentAs(typeof(string), null).ToString();
                break;
            case "EmailBody":
                mail.Body = xReader.ReadElementContentAs(typeof(string), null).ToString();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return mail;
}
```

And the XML file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Email>
    <FromAddress>website@domain.co.uk</FromAddress>
    <ToAddress>to@domain.co.uk</ToAddress>
    <Subject>Contact us enquiry</Subject>
    <EmailBody>
        <![CDATA[
        <html>
           <head>
              <title>Customer Enquiry</title>
           </head>
            <div valign="top">
                <!-- center -->
                <font color="#666666" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, Verdana" size="2">
                  <p>You have recieved a new customer enquiry.</p>
                  <p><strong>Name: </strong>{0}<br />
                  <strong>Email: </strong>{1}<br />
                  <strong>Tel: </strong>{2}<br /></p>
                  <p><strong>Message: </strong>{3}</p>
                </font>
            </div>
          </html> 
      ]]>
    </EmailBody>
</Email>
```

Comment: do you mean that i want to share that image online or else where ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? If you want to include images in the body of your email you need to set `IsBodyHtml = true;` and then design as normal. If the image is external then you would use that external link as the `src` attribute on the tag.

Comment: i am using `IsBodyHtml = true` and img tag as `<img src="images/imgnm.jpg" width="277" height="167" alt=""/>` in HTML.

Comment: That's a relative path. You need to use an absolute one.

Comment: I know, i'm not using one in my example but im sure you know how to write your own? Your example with the correct format src attribute `<img src="www.example.com/images/imgnm.jpg" width="277" height="167" alt=""/>`

Comment: could you please tell me how can i assign path to **<img src=""/>** tag... my image resides under `images` folder within my project.

Comment: I've written what you need to use above. **www.YOURWEBSITE.com/images/YOURIMAGE.png**

Comment: Can you give me reason why that images displayed only in **gmail,ymail** not in **reddifmail, outlook** ?

Comment: Have you clicked to download images or are you blocking images in those clients? HTML email is a savage beast and there are many things that could be wrong with it. If you have another question you should start a new thread.

Comment: Yes, but there are no images in `view page resources` and my **blocking images** option is **true**, no luck !! i have started new thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643381/external-images-not-displayed-on-all-major-mail-clients-while-sending-mail

Answer (score 0):

```
Guid contentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
  "This is a image:<br /><img src=\"cid:" + contentId + "\" />", 
  null, "text/html");

ContentType ct = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);

LinkedResource embedded = new LinkedResource("c:\\image1.jpg", ct);
embedded.ContentId = contentId;
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(embedded);

mail.AlternateViews.Add(altView);
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score -1):

I would probably do this by having the image stored on my hosting service and linking to it using a normal  tag with the src being the link to where it is stored. That way as long as your hosting doesn't go down, you can always get the image.

Remember to make sure that the email has the HTML value set to true and you should be fine.

Comment: do you mean that i want to share that image online or else where ?

Comment: Basically I had the same idea as the winning answer. Again, downvoter care to comment?